# Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android

`Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.125project/com.example.125project.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

This error comes up when I try to start my LoginActivity from my MainActivity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.125project">
...
    <application
...
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    </application>
```

The problem is, I have defined this class in my manifest. In fact, it was working right up until it wasn't. I had a friend download the same exact version of the code that I am using and it works fine for him. How can I work around this?

Comment: Try gradle sync if that does not work try go to select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button

Comment: use clean project from Build->Clean Project hope it will work fine then